# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el objeto de la clase PropertyChangeEvent utilizando el método getNewValue() en la implementación del patrón observer?

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño, cast

estoy practicando ejercicios de Java sobre el patrón Observer con la clase PropertyChangeListener. Estoy teniendo el siguiente error por pantalla al querer castear la siguiente linea, y no entiendo muy bien el por que, o como debería de hacerlo:

```
Product product = (Product) event.getNewValue();
```

[image: Error que aparece]

Os dejo por aquí también las clases que estoy implementando:

**Clase Product**

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

//Objeto observable

public class Product {
    private String name;
    private int stock;
    private PropertyChangeSupport change = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    Product(String name, int stock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.stock = stock;
        change = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        change.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        change.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void decreaseStock(int quantity) {
        change.firePropertyChange("stock", stock, (stock - quantity));
        stock -= quantity;
    }

}
```

**Clase Provider**

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

//Objeto observador
public class Provider implements PropertyChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        String eventName = event.getPropertyName();
        if (eventName.equals("stock")) {
            Product product = (Product) event.getNewValue();
            System.out.println("El stock ha bajado. El stock actual es "+product.getStock());
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product product = new Product("Patatas fritas", 12);

        Provider provider = new Provider();

        product.addPropertyChangeListener(provider);

        product.decreaseStock(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En le Product has establecido que se producira una cambio en la propiedad `stock`. El valor de este cambio es un numero entero `stock-quantity`.

En otras palabras, al escuchar la propiedad "stock" y obtener su valor, te devolverá el numero que de la operación.

```
Product product = (Product) event.getNewValue();
```

Como devuelve un entero, cuando realizas lo anterior estas diciendo que el numero Integer que te devuelve la propiedad de stock, lo transforme a Product, lo cual no tiene sentido. No es posible convertir un valor entero a Product.

En tu ejemplo, los valores devuelven lo siguiente:

```
getOldValue = 12
getNewValue = 2 (esto por la operación 12-10)
```

Si quieres obtener el Product en el que se ha realizado el cambio de propiedad tienes que utilizar el método

```
getSource()
```

La documentación dice que este método devuelve el objeto donde se produjo el evento.
Es decir, un `Product` en este caso.

```
Product product = (Product) event.getSource();
```

Eso te tendría que devolver lo que has imprimido en consola

```
El stock ha bajado. El stock actual es 12
```

---

Por cierto, otra observación, en consola te devuelve 12 porque el método que escucha la propiedad se ejecuta antes del cambio de la variable stock. Es decir, getStock devuelve 12 porque aún no se ha cambiado según el orden de ejecucion.

Para que te devuelve 2 tienes que cambiar la variable a la vez que defines el nuevo valor, es decir algo así:

```
change.firePropertyChange("stock", stock, stock=stock-quantity);
```

De esa manera defines el valor de stock a la vez que le pasas el nuevo valor.

```
El stock ha bajado. El stock actual es 2
```

Comment: Buenas! Efectivamente.. eso era lo que me pasaba. Estaba utilizando el método erróneo, con el getResource() si que puedo acceder al objeto. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: De nada! Me alegro de ayudarte.